# Проблема с файлом "обработчиком" в php

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, jquery-ui

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, информация с формы не заносится в базу , но стоит мне убрать id="datepicker"   из строчки

```
       <input name = "datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" value="" />
```

Сразу всё начинает работать (но id="datepicker" нужен для работы календарь из JQuery)

Код формы:

```
 <form action="reserve_room_process.php" method="post">   
              <input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["username"];?>" />
              <input name="name" type="hidden" value="<?php echo  $nameOfUser; ?>" />
              <input name="room" type="hidden" value="1" />
              <p>Choose time for meeting room: 

   <input name = "datepicker" type="text" id="datepicker" value="" />
              <select name="time">
              <option value="9">9:00</option>;
              <option value="10">10:00</option>;
              <option value="11">11:00</option>;
              <option value="12">12:00</option>;
              <option value="13">13:00</option>;
              <option value="14">14:00</option>;
              <option value="15">15:00</option>;
              <option value="16">16:00</option>;
              <option value="17">17:00</option>;
              <option value="14">18:00</option>;
              <option value="14">19:00</option>;
              </select> 

             </p>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reserve" /> <br /><br />  
        <!--  <a href="manage_content.php">Cancel</a>-->
       </table>


          </form>
```

Код обработчика:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    

    $user_id = $_POST["user_id"];
    $name    = $_POST["name"];
    $time    = (int) $_POST["time"];
    $date = $_POST["datepicker"];
  $room = $_POST["room"];
    $visible = 0 ;
  $currentTime = (int)date('H');

  $query  = "INSERT INTO room_reserv (user_id , name , rtime , rdate, room) VALUES  ('{$user_id}' , '{$name}' ,'{$time}' , '{$date}', '{$room}') ";

  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));


      redirect_to("discussion.php");


}
```

Comment: Так как сервер знать не знает какие у вас там на форме `id`, значит вероятно у вас есть какая-то js-магия передающая данные на сервер.

Comment: у меня всего лишь стандартная библиотека Jquery c datepicker, не подскажете что нужно дописать чтоб заработало?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте задать другое название, например

```
<input name = "date_picker" type="text" id="datepicker" value="" />
```